# Definition of quotient category

Tags: category-theory, definition

Is there any reason why only gluing of morphisms sharing domain and codomain is usually allowed in the definition of quotient category?

Comment: Because it's the easy case where the functor to the quotient is surjective.

Comment: @ZhenLin I understand that it's the easy case, but isn't the functor to the quotient allways surjective?

Comment: No. You may have to add new composites in the quotient.

Comment: Oh, I see. Easy example is gluing domain and codomain of a single non-endomorphism.

Comment: There is however a method for computing arbitrary quotients in cat, see e.g. _generalized congruences - Epimorphisms in $\mathcal{Cat}$_ by Marek A. Bednarczyk et al

Answer (score 0):

So you want to identify $f : A \to B$ with $f' : A' \to B'$ even if $A,A'$ and $B,B'$ have nothing to do with each other? But this means that at least in the quotient we will need isomorphisms $A \cong A'$ and $B \cong B'$ such that $f,f'$ get identified along these. But adding some new morphisms between given objects is not the task of quotients. This is a different type of free construction.

Comment: Identifying $f$ with $f'$ just implies identifying their domains and codomains as well. This is how congruences work.